# Can I make shell consider NBSP a whitespace character?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, unicode, whitespace

This seems like a common issue: you paste a simple command from somewhere into the terminal and it's not being understood by a shell:

```
$ echo test
$ zsh: command not found: echo test
```

The reason is because the words are separated with [NBSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) instead of space. Can the shell be instructed to consider NBSP a whitespace character?

Comment: Sounds that the problem here is that your clipboard contains the wrong character, not that `zsh` is not breaking on the non-breaking space. Rather than changing the syntax of the shell, a better work around (for that issue that is *not* in zsh) could be to replace those nbsps with spcs (which they were meant to be in the first place) after pasting.

Comment: @Eugene Yarmash I cannot reproduce this at all. What terminal and OS do you use?

Comment: @Marlon See the linked [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods) for some methods. For example, in macOS you can type `⌥ Option` + `Space` to get an NBSP character. This can be reproduced in bash or zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas agreed, it's the wrong character, but when copying and pasting from some sites' tutorials "out there" it can be a problem not of the learner's making.

Comment: @Eugene Yarmash I know how to produce a non-breaking space; that’s not what I meant. What I meant is that when I copy-paste text containing an nbsp into my terminal, it works just fine in Zsh for me. I made an HTML page that contains `echo&nbsp;test`, then copy-pasted from Safari into Terminal.app and it works the exact same as if I had typed `echo test`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your terminal supports bracketed paste, you can redefine the zsh paste widget to substitute non-breaking spaces. For example:

```
    bracketed-paste-subst() {                  
        local content
        zle .bracketed-paste -N content
        YANK_START=CURSOR 
        LBUFFER+="${content//$'\u00a0'/ }" 
        YANK_END=CURSOR 
        zle -f yank 2> /dev/null
    }
    zle -N bracketed-paste-subst
    bindkey "^[[200~" bracketed-paste-subst
```

In theory, you can add non-breaking space to the `IFS` variable to have it be treated as a word separator but I'm not sure that works for non-ASCII and it isn't a good idea to do that anyway.

Comment: `$IFS` is only involved in `read`, unquoted `$=var` and command substitution, not in the shell grammar tokenisation.